# ¿Cómo eliminar definitivamente composer de Linux?

Tags: laravel-5, linux, composer

¿Cómo puedo eliminar definitivamente `composer` de `linux`? Estoy trabajando con `Laravel` y se me ha presentado un problema y he decidido eliminar `composer` definitivamente y empezar desde cero con la instalación.

Answer (score 1):

Depende de cómo lo hayas instalado pero entiendo que lo habrás hecho a través del manual oficial.

En este caso es simple:

Tienes que eliminar el archivo `composer.phar`.

Eliminar la carpeta de cache: `/home/<user>/.composer`

El `composer.phar` lo puedes buscar con locate sino sabes dónde lo colocaste en la instalación con un `locate composer.phar`

Answer (score 0):

Encontrar y eliminar. (si no lo instalaste con un gestor de paquetes como yum, apt-get o similar)

```
[root]# which composer
/path/composer
[root]# rm -f  /path/composer
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer apt-get remove del paquete de manera que no dejas nada en el equipo